# Text input border color not changing correctly on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a text input border to be blue when it is not selected and when the field is selected, the border color should change to orange.

```css
input[type="text"]{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}

input[type="text"]:focus{
   border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

[image: This is the text box when not selected]
[image: This is the text box when selected. But the border color is not orange.]

Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: Try including `outline: none;` in the `:focus` rule.

Answer (score 12):

The border changes but there is an `outline` that covers it. Reset it on `focus` like this:

```css
input[type="text"]{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }

 input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It works in edge without the outline. But in chrome you need the outline tag. Thanks.

Comment: @PrathameshPrabhudesai N.b.: it’s not an “outline tag”, it’s called outline _property_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this since I don't like any of those default styling and prefer that I do my own.

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Why would you affect the overall performance of your website by targeting every element on your DOM when you don't really need to? Plus, outline exists for accessibility reasons.